# ComboBox.SelectedText Property and Database Error

Tags: vb.net, ssms

This specific code `ComboBox2.SelectedItem` query has an error to my database. I think I'm missing something with this code `ComboBox2.SelectedItem`:

```
Private Sub UpdateCombo()
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()

        SQLcon.Open()
        Dim Command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = SQLcon.CreateCommand()
        Command.CommandText = "Select productName From tblProductsStocks"
        Dim SQLReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        While SQLReader.Read()
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(SQLReader.Item("productName"))
        End While
        SQLcon.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
SQLcon.Open()
        Dim Command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = SQLcon.CreateCommand()
        Command.CommandText = "Select * From tblProductsStocks WHERE productName=" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem
        Dim SQLReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        SQLReader.Read()
        TextBox1.Text = SQLReader.Item("productType")
        TextBox2.Text = SQLReader.Item("productMass")
        SQLcon.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add a parameter to the command. Set the `.Value` to `ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()`. You should check whether `SelectedIndex < 0` and `Return` if it is.

Comment: To be honest, I would suggest doing this rather differently.  Rather than just retrieving `productName` initially, retrieve all three columns.  Populate a `DataTable`, either using a data reader or data adapter, and then bind that `DataTable` to the `ComboBox` and the `TextBoxes`.  After that, you need no code at all to populate the `TextBoxes`.  Selecting an item in the `ComboBox` will automatically update other controls bound to the same data.

Comment: To address the question as asked, the issue is that you are not quoting a string in your SQL code.  Just as you need to wrap a `String` literal in double-quotes in VB code, so you need to wrap string literals in single-quotes in SQL code.  If you were to look at your SQL code, which you should already have done, you would see that the value from the `ComboBox` is not quoted.  The solution, rather than quoting the literal, is to not use a literal at all.  As suggested, you should ALWAYS be using parameters when inserting variables into SQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Connections need to be disposed as well as closed to be returned to the connection pool. If there is an error, your code may not even close the connection. If you keep your database objects local, you can control that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error. In my code the Command is part of the Using block. Note the comma after the connection constructor.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise pass the command text and the connection to the command constructor.

Use parameters. Not only does it avoids errors concatenating strings but it also avoids Sql injection. In your code, the selected item is meant to be a string but you have failed to add the surrounding single quotes. This is not needed when you use parameters. Command text is executable code to the server and a malicious user can enter things that would ruin you database. Parameters are considered as values by the server, not executable code so they are much safer.

Open the connection at the last possible moment, right before the .Execute...  Connections are precious resources and need to be opened, closed and disposed as quickly as possible. The connection must be open as long as the reader is engaged. So I moved updating the user interface (the text boxes) to outside the using block.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim String1 As String = ""
    Dim String2 As String = ""
    Using SQLcon As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
        Command As New SqlCommand("Select * From tblProductsStocks WHERE productName= @producName", SQLcon)
        'Check your database for the actual datatype and field size
        Command.Parameters.Add("@productName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
        SQLcon.Open()
        Dim SQLReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        SQLReader.Read()
        String1 = SQLReader.Item("productType").ToString
        String2 = SQLReader.Item("productMass").ToString
    End Using 'closes and disposes the connection and command
    TextBox1.Text = String1
    TextBox2.Text = String2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :) !!! and your suggestion about Using and Dim Strings. I totally get why you must use. I'm actually new about coding so, yeah